# How to create like an option group on a subform in MS Access so that only one subrecord can be selected at a time?

Tags: vba, ms-access

let's say

I have a customer form and a subform of customer addresses. I would like to be able to mark only one subrecord as the default so that it is used for all mailings. How can I do this?

Comment: A yes/no field named IsPrimary in addresses table and apply filter criteria to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibel solutions for this!

One is to have a combobox in the main form, where you can select a record from the subform.

See the green marked field in the picture below.

[image]

ALTERNATIVE 2:
Use a checkbox to mark the default mailing address.

[image]

With this one you may want to make sure that not two addresses can be checked. That can be done in the BeforeUpdate event for the checkbox with code like:

```
Private Sub DefaultAddress_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    ' If checkbox is set to true
    If Me!DefaultAddress Then
        ' If there if an other address already chosen
        If DCount("*", "CompanyAddresses", _
        "DefaultAddress AND CompanyID = " & Me!CompanyID) > 0 Then
            Cancel = True ' Cancel this checkbox
            MsgBox "You have to uncheck the previous default address " & _
            "before selecting a new one!", vbExclamation, "Set default address"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

ALTERNATIVE 3: Is like alt 2 but with code that automatically uncheck previous checked address, before selecting a new default address. This option needs more advanced VBA-code.

ALTERNATIVE 4: Is like alt 2 but instead of a checkbox you can use combobox like the one in the picture labled 'Befattning'.

Comment: Thats an idea, What is the other possible solutions you're talking about ?

Comment: Added 3 more alternative solutions in my first answer :)